# Show that if $r>1$ and $a>0$ then $(a + r^n)^{1/n}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that if $r>1$  and $a>0$ then $(a + r^n)^{1/n}$ converges.

This answer must rely principally on the idea that the limit of a sum is the sum of the limits, and unfortunately, cannot employ consequences of this theorem.

Comment: I do not see any sums in the problem statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It it is allowed, you can use Squeezing. We have
$$r^n\lt a+r^n\lt ar^n+r^n.$$
Taking $n$-th roots we get
$$r\lt (a+r^n)^{1/n}\lt (a+1)^{1/n} r.$$
But $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a+1)^{1/n}=1$.

**Another way:** Rewrite our expression as 
$$r\left(1+\frac{a}{r^n}\right)^{1/n}.$$
Now use the fact that if $t\gt 0$ then 
$$1\lt (1+t)^{1/n}\le 1+\frac{t}{n}.$$
Here $t=\frac{a}{r^n}$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

$${(r^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}}\leq {(a + r^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}}\leq ({{r^n+r^n)}^{\frac{1}{n}}}$$

Answer (score 0):

If allowed, this is a routine application of L'Hopital's rule after writing
$(a + r^n)^{1/n}$ as $e^{(ln (a + r^n))/n}$.